# Como puedo obtener la id en la ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Como puedo obtener la id en la ventana modal?

```
var items = [
  <?php while($reg=  mysql_fetch_array($order)){ ?>
      {
          id: <?php echo $reg["id"]; ?>,
          title: '<?php echo $reg["titulo"]; ?>',
       }, 
  <?php } ?> 

onItemClick: function(item) {
  console.log("Clicked: " + item);
  $('#orden').modal('show');
},
```

Comment: Hola @jonny. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Creo que simplificaría mucho la pregunta si evitaras la parte de PHP y directamente publicaras el código JavaScript. Incluso te ayudaría a ver que tu objeto tiene comas de más y el array no lo estás cerrando con un `]`. Intenta generar un [mcve]. Además, ¿qué elemento tiene la clase `orden`, y cuándo se ejecuta `onItemClick`?

Comment: @jonny podrías poner el error que tenes?